# XCode 4.2 crashes on Snow Leopard

Tags: ios, xcode4

Just got the XCode 4.2 for iOS SDK 5.0 installed on Snow Leopard. Just keeps on crashing.

I installed to /Developer4/ to keep my previous XCode 3 around, just in case.

Anyone got this problem? Solved it?

Edit:
When I start a new project, I get this error:

> ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-937/Framework/Classes/Model/SourceControl/IDESourceControlTree.m:119
>   Details:  Invalid location for source tree.  Initialization failed.
>   Object:   
>   Method:   -initWithDictionary:sourceControlExtension:sourceControlManager:
>   Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1}
>   Hints:
>     0: Replacement view is installing: 
>   Backtrace:
>     0  0x00000001009e6646 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
>     1  0x000000010006aaa4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
>     2  0x00000001005a314f -[IDESourceControlTree initWithDictionary:sourceControlExtension:sourceControlManager:] (in IDEFoundation)
>     3  0x00000001005a2900 -[IDESourceControlRepository initWithDictionary:sourceControlExtension:sourceControlManager:] (in IDEFoundation)
>     4  0x00000001005a20ac -[IDESourceControlManager loadRepositories] (in IDEFoundation)
>     5  0x000000010059cc9b -[IDESourceControlManager init] (in IDEFoundation)
>     6  0x000000010059cad2 __53+[IDESourceControlManager sharedSourceControlManager]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEFoundation)
>     7  0x00007fff86e7c705 dispatch_once_f (in libSystem.B.dylib)
>     8  0x000000010059caa1 +[IDESourceControlManager sharedSourceControlManager] (in IDEFoundation)
>     9  0x00000001006732d1 +[IDESnapshotsManager sourceControlSystemUsedForSnapshotsWithError:] (in IDEFoundation)
>    10  0x000000010067326d -[IDESnapshotsManager areSnapshotsEnabled] (in IDEFoundation)
>    11  0x0000000100b66369 -[IDESnapshotsListController loadAllCommits] (in IDEKit)
>    12  0x0000000100b65acc -[IDESnapshotsListController loadView] (in IDEKit)
>    13  0x00007fff830e36a3 -[NSViewController view] (in AppKit)
>    14  0x000000010021dc7b -[DVTViewController view] (in DVTKit)
>    15  0x0000000100220e00 __42-[DVTReplacementView _setupViewController]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
>    16  0x000000010002e85e DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
>    17  0x0000000100220cd3 -[DVTReplacementView _setupViewController] (in DVTKit)
>    18  0x0000000100220ba5 -[DVTReplacementView installedViewController] (in DVTKit)
>    19  0x000000010022bc8c -[DVTReplacementView layoutTopDown] (in DVTKit)
>    20  0x000000010021ba33 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
>    21  0x000000010021bae2 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
>    22  0x000000010021bae2 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
>    23  0x000000010021bae2 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
>    24  0x000000010021bae2 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
>    25  0x000000010021bae2 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
>    26  0x000000010021bae2 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
>    27  0x000000010021bae2 __84+[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTKit)
>    28  0x000000010021b8a7 +[DVTAutoLayoutView _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:] (in DVTKit)
>    29  0x000000010022b878 -[DVTDelayedValidator doValidation:] (in DVTKit)
>    30  0x00007fff869e8441 __NSFirePerformWithOrder (in Foundation)
>    31  0x00007fff83be6b37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
>    32  0x00007fff83bc2464 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
>    33  0x00007fff83bc1dbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
>    34  0x00007fff8194a7ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
>    35  0x00007fff8194a551 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
>    36  0x00007fff8194a4ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
>    37  0x00007fff830fceb2 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
>    38  0x00007fff830fc801 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
>    39  0x00007fff830c268f -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
>    40  0x00007fff830bb3b0 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
>    41  0x0000000100000eec
>    42  0x0000000000000002

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think I found what caused the problem. I had some slumbering (unused) settings for source control that came along from previous XCode versions. I never used that source control feature anyway, but it made XCode 4 crash hard. Removing that (Organizer) and XCode 4 seems stable so far...