# Xcode 5 crashes with SVN version 1.7 - self signed certificate

Tags: svn, crash, certificate, xcode5, self-signed

I've updated to XCode 5 today (using the Mac AppStore) and ever since it keeps crashing whenever I open my previous projects (that are working copies of repos located in my local SVN).

The error report contains infos (IDESourceControlCredentialsValidator) that indicate that XCode has some issues with my SVN:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-3532/Framework/Classes/Protocols/DVTInvalidation.m:243
Details:  <IDESourceControlCredentialsValidator, 0x7f8df10808f0> was never invalidated.
```

And yes it appears to be the reason. When I open XCode and click "Check out an existing project" it crashes as soon as I've entered the server address and it started to connect.

In order to still be able to work, I've opened XCode-Preferences-Source Control and unchecked "Enable Source Control". So for now I have to use another SVN Tool to check in & update my repo aside from XCode.

Has anyone got an idea how this could be fixed? Or does anyone have a similar issue?

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate?  If so, I guess this applies: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/204128?tstart=0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also faced this problem. To prevent xCode5 from Crashing follow these steps.
Xcdoe > Preferences > Source Control > Uncheck the Enable Source control . After that Xcode will not Crash .. :)

Answer (score 5):

They didn't bother adding the UI controls to allow you to bypass the validity check for a SVN certificate. I have a self-signed cert on my svn server and this solution solved it for me.
You have to "svn info url" in the terminal and (p) permanently accept that certificate. After that, xcode will work.

Solution found here: http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/fixing-subversion-problem-error-validating-server-certificate/

Comment: I also had to run the command chmod 644 ~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server/* to get it to permanently accept the certificate

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue and solved it.
on previous xcode versions I used absolute ip address to checkout the project (e.g `https://10.0.0.1:8443`)
but of course this doesn't match the hostname specified by server's certificate.
so I used the terminal command line to make commit all my code and then I opened a new folder and re-checkedout the project, this time using the hostname as the svn address (e.g `https://{hostname}:8443`)

then, on Xcode 5, open xcode without all previous projects (press alt+shift when clicking the xcode icon to do this) . go to your preferences and press the accounts tab. there you should see your old repository address, delete it.

now open your project from the new re-checkeout folder you made in the previous steps.
viola - all should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - thanks to the link trojanfoe gave me, I was able to make XCode play nice with my repos again. Jordan Upham's reply did the job: https://devforums.apple.com/message/887478#887478

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Nishith Sheth for your answer, however, although this does indeed stop Xcode crashing, it means you will need to use svn from outside of Xcode. For me, this wasn't a permanent solution.

I estimate the problem revolves around your working copy being upgraded to svn 1.7, yet your svn client is  1.6.x. To check your version of svn open the terminal and type:

svn --version

If you see that the version is 1.6.x or less you will need to upgrade your version of svn. This can be acheived simply by going to Xcode > Preferences... > Downloads.

[image]

Install the Command Line Tools, which will also install the svn 1.7 client. Once it has installed, check the version of svn, it should now say 1.7.

Close Xcode and fire it up again and it should no longer crash and you should be able to use svn from Xcode once again.

For more information, and the place I found my answer, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/1287405) answer.