# Xcode 5 crashes -- Xcode quit unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode5

Xcode 5 from the App Store crashes when I select any file in the Project Navigator or when I try to edit it. I have deleted all plugins and the derived data for the app and it keeps crashing.

Does anyone know how to fix this and why this is happening?

Below is the first part of the error.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1412
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-3532/Framework/Classes/Protocols/DVTInvalidation.m:243
Details:  <IDESourceControlCredentialsValidator, 0x7faec5e3c9b0> was never invalidated.
```

I am not sure this helps but here is the Backtrace

```
Backtrace for allocation (if _creationBacktrace is set):
 (null)
Object:   <IDESourceControlCredentialsValidator: 0x7f86dceeb080>
Method:   -dealloc
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f86d8414c80>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010e3a1188 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010d137655 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010d137984 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010d20c6a6 _DVTInvalidation_DeallocSuper (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010e33e2a3 -[IDESourceControlSSLAuthenticationWindowController .cxx_destruct] (in IDEKit)
  5  0x00007fff8c00bfcc object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  6  0x00007fff8c005922 objc_destructInstance (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  7  0x00007fff8c005fa0 object_dispose (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  8  0x000000010d161995 __DVTSetupKVODeallocAssertions_block_invoke_371 (in DVTFoundation)
  9  0x00007fff865797fa -[NSResponder dealloc] (in AppKit)
 10  0x00007fff864af162 -[NSWindowController dealloc] (in AppKit)
 11  0x00007fff86623901 -[NSWindowController release] (in AppKit)
 12  0x00007fff867595b0 -[NSAutounbinder dealloc] (in AppKit)
 13  0x00007fff8c006230 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) (in libobjc.A.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff87a0cd72 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop (in CoreFoundation)
 15  0x00007fff8c52447a -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] (in Foundation)
 16  0x00007fff8657a27e -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 17  0x00007fff8651ebd6 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 18  0x00007fff91f377e1 start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad212 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fcb54 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a840dce abort + 143
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e3a0a93 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:reason:] + 763
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e3a12ee -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1117
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d137655 _DVTAssertionHandler + 421
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d137984 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 322
7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d20c6a6 _DVTInvalidation_DeallocSuper + 480
8   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010e33e2a3 -[IDESourceControlSSLAuthenticationWindowController .cxx_destruct] + 94
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8c00bfcc object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 100
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8c005922 objc_destructInstance + 91
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8c005fa0 object_dispose + 22
12  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010d161995 __DVTSetupKVODeallocAssertions_block_invoke_371 + 264
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff865797fa -[NSResponder dealloc] + 129
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff864af162 -[NSWindowController dealloc] + 616
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86623901 -[NSWindowController release] + 159
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff867595b0 -[NSAutounbinder dealloc] + 51
17  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8c006230 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 464
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a0cd72 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 34
19  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c52447a -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 154
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8657a27e -[NSApplication run] + 736
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8651ebd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff91f377e1 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903add16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8641cdea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8641c9ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ab686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903aac42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a0c233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a11916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a110e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c501546 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 356
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c55f562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fb7a2 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ab686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903aac42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a0c233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a11916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a110e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011466875a -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 164
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c55f562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fb7a2 _pthread_start + 327
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad322 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a50f46 __CFSocketManager + 1302
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fb7a2 _pthread_start + 327
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ab686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903aac42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a0c233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a11916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a110e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c5647ee -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 268
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c4fd1aa -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x0000000118afe9bb -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 132
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c55f562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fb7a2 _pthread_start + 327
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fffe9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8b5872a1 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 689
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8b586fd7 startIOThread(void*) + 148
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fb7a2 _pthread_start + 327
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fffe9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113436166 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c55f562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fb7a2 _pthread_start + 327
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fffe9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113436166 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c55f562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fb7a2 _pthread_start + 327
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad0fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fffe9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000113436166 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c55f562 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fb7a2 _pthread_start + 327
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdf4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdf4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdf4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdf4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdf4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad6d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdf4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fdd13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ab686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903aac42 mach_msg + 70
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a0c233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a11916 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87a110e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff8728a590 SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 356
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fb7a2 _pthread_start + 327
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff903ad386 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a885800 nanosleep + 163
2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff8fee2358 0x7fff8fecc000 + 90968
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7fb7a2 _pthread_start + 327
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a7e81e1 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff52b72108  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000c07  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff52b72130  rsp: 0x00007fff52b72108
   r8: 0x00007fff769b7278   r9: 0x0000000000000141  r10: 0x0000000020000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff52b72248  r13: 0x000000010ea71680  r14: 0x00007fff769b8180  r15: 0x00007fff52b721f0
  rip: 0x00007fff903ad212  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007f86d883a400
Logical CPU: 0
```

Comment: Do anyone know how to fix this and why this is happening? Has anyone else seen this happening?

Comment: Have you tried deleting Xcode.app from Finder and downloading a new copy?

Comment: I deleted Xcode  and reinstalled from app store .... same thing happens ...

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you have now? 5A1412 was distributed as the GM seed but there is a 5A1413 available today. Check the App Store for updates.

Comment: Xcode 5 5A1413 is a major §%"§/%)!! Everything worked with the GM seed, now any OpenGL ES app crashes on Simulator when GL context is created. I get logging issues on device (NSLog from static lib won't appear) and a number of other really whacky bugs. Reboot, reinstall, nothing helps.

Comment: solved it - check out my answer at a similar ticket
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/19078588/1126757][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19078588/1126757

Comment: I found it to be this problem;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656011/xcode-5-x-maverick-crashes-on-file-operations

Answer (score 57):

I have also faced this problem. To prevent xCode5 from Crashing follow these steps.
Xcdoe > Preferences > Source Control > Uncheck the Enable Source control . After that Xcode will not Crash .. :)

Comment: I just spent about 4hrs in full on panic mode when Xcode suddenly crashed, and wouldn't let me open my project without locking up again. The built in version control is at fault, and it had buggered up my userinterfacestate file, which shouldn't have been in there in the first place. Once I went in and deleted the file, the project opened right up, and I promptly disabled Xcode's version control system.

Comment: so for commit file and other svn operation we have to use other tools?

Comment: I guess yes, until Apple fix this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help for me :(

Comment: Another option might be to delete the user-specific config files inside your Xcode project...

Comment: My Xcode was crashing every time I tried to add a new Target Dependency to my target, something I thought would be unrelated to source control. I was wrong! Thanks for the suggestion, it solved my problem.

Comment: Unbelievably someone can give this answer. How can you disable source control if it is there for ease in communication with the source control manager.Also there is nothing that apple is gonna fix about xcode. 

It crashes when you request more than expected requests to do. As a result xcode being unaware to know what operations to perform, first it disable itself and crashes....LOL

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem for the first time while using Xcode 6.1.

I had just cloned the project and it was crashing as soon as the Indexing process would start. I disabled source control as suggested in the previous answer and it was still crashing.

In my case, the problem was that the Destination was a device that was connected to my MAC at that time but was not included in any of the Provisioning Profiles that I had installed on my MAC. Changing the Destination to any of the simulators before the Indexing process would start fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Its really annoying. Did you find any fix for this?

Comment: Have you checked that the Destination is not a Device but one of the simulator options? Once I selected an iOS Simulator it stopped crashing and after cleaning the project I could build for an iOS Simulator or a Device without problems.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while upgrading from xcode7.2 to 7.3.
Everything was fine except the conflicting **PLUGINs**.

Try removing plugins you might have installed in xcode and it will work. In my case Alcatraz plugin was the culprit. Just removed it from the path **/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode** and all went good.

**P.S** : Make sure your mac OS is compatible with the xcode you are installing!! sometimes blindly installing xcode without upgrading OS (like I was doing ;) ) can cause such hazardous behaviour. Best Luck!!