# XCode 5 : crash again and again while opening application

Tags: xcode5

New XCode 5 crashes again and again when I am launching it.
It works fine yesterday. But today it crashes.
I am opening XCode, it open last opened application and trying to indexing, while indexing it got crashes.

I have restart my machine so many times but no help, even I also repair disk permission.

Crash Log :

```
Process:         Xcode [559]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0 (3332.25)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3332025000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 38302662
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [249]
User ID:         503

Date/Time:       2013-09-26 12:47:37.593 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F37)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          19785 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           12
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  2915 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   12
Anonymous UUID:                      283DD523-90AB-ABAE-E59C-339E94D6623D

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-3532/Framework/Classes/Protocols/DVTInvalidation.m:243
Details:  <IDESourceControlCredentialsValidator, 0x7f7fd95071d0> was never invalidated.

Backtrace for allocation (if _creationBacktrace is set):
 (null)
Object:   <IDESourceControlCredentialsValidator: 0x7f7fd95071d0>
Method:   -dealloc
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f7fd2414ce0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010efbd188 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010dd53655 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010dd53984 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010de286a6 _DVTInvalidation_DeallocSuper (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010ef5a2a3 -[IDESourceControlSSLAuthenticationWindowController .cxx_destruct] (in IDEKit)
  5  0x00007fff8b749fcc object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  6  0x00007fff8b743922 objc_destructInstance (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  7  0x00007fff8b743fa0 object_dispose (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  8  0x000000010dd7d995 __DVTSetupKVODeallocAssertions_block_invoke_371 (in DVTFoundation)
  9  0x00007fff9246f7fa -[NSResponder dealloc] (in AppKit)
 10  0x00007fff923a5162 -[NSWindowController dealloc] (in AppKit)
 11  0x00007fff92519901 -[NSWindowController release] (in AppKit)
 12  0x00007fff9264f5b0 -[NSAutounbinder dealloc] (in AppKit)
 13  0x00007fff8b744230 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) (in libobjc.A.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff88870d72 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop (in CoreFoundation)
 15  0x00007fff87a0a47a -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] (in Foundation)
 16  0x00007fff9247027e -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 17  0x00007fff92414bd6 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 18  0x00007fff920737e1 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 19  0x0000000000000002

abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf50212 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8be5db24 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8bea1f61 abort + 143
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010efbca93 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:reason:] + 763
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010efbd2ee -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1117
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010dd53655 _DVTAssertionHandler + 421
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010dd53984 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 322
7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010de286a6 _DVTInvalidation_DeallocSuper + 480
8   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010ef5a2a3 -[IDESourceControlSSLAuthenticationWindowController .cxx_destruct] + 94
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8b749fcc object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 100
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8b743922 objc_destructInstance + 91
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8b743fa0 object_dispose + 22
12  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010dd7d995 __DVTSetupKVODeallocAssertions_block_invoke_371 + 264
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9246f7fa -[NSResponder dealloc] + 129
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff923a5162 -[NSWindowController dealloc] + 616
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92519901 -[NSWindowController release] + 159
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9264f5b0 -[NSAutounbinder dealloc] + 51
17  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8b744230 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 464
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff88870d72 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 34
19  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff87a0a47a -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 154
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9247027e -[NSApplication run] + 736
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92414bd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff920737e1 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf50386 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8bee6c85 pthread_join + 847
2   libclang.dylib                  0x0000000110d3904a 0x110566000 + 8204362
3   libclang.dylib                  0x000000011057fbed clang_indexSourceFile + 877
4   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e794349 -[IDEIndexClangTranslationUnit indexUsingDataSource:] + 424
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e793337 -[IDEIndexClangDataSource generateDataForJob:] + 2966
6   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e79260f -[IDEIndexDataSource processJob:] + 152
7   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e79217f +[IDEIndexingEngine runFileJob:] + 696
8   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e7918c3 -[IDEIndexingJob run] + 159
9   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010e951a60 __40-[IDEIndexingJobScheduler _scheduleJobs]_block_invoke + 33
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a64f01 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a610b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a621fa _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 304
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8be5ecdb _pthread_wqthread + 404
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8be49191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8bf50d16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a63dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a639ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Thread 4:

Thread 5:

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader

Thread 7:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority

Thread 8:

Thread 9:: com.apple.CFSocket.private

Thread 10:

Thread 11:: DYMobileDeviceManager

Thread 12:: CVDisplayLink

Thread 13:

Thread 14:

Thread 15:

Thread 16:

Thread 17:

Thread 18:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority

Thread 19:

Thread 20:

Thread 21:

Thread 22:

Thread 23:

Thread 24:

Thread 25:

Thread 26:

Thread 27:

Thread 28:

Thread 29:

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff51f52118  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000c07  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff51f52140  rsp: 0x00007fff51f52118
   r8: 0x00007fff782cc278   r9: 0x0000000000000077  r10: 0x0000000020000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff51f52258  r13: 0x000000010f68d680  r14: 0x00007fff782cd180  r15: 0x00007fff51f52200
  rip: 0x00007fff8bf50212  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff782c5ff0
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 2
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 275
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=340.0M resident=192.7M(57%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=147.3M(43%)
Writable regions: Total=1.3G written=134.1M(10%) resident=177.5M(13%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.1G(87%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
CG backing stores                    6620K
CG image                              636K
CG raster data                        212K
CG shared images                     1216K
CoreAnimation                         416K
CoreImage                               8K
CoreServices                         3760K
IOKit                                9380K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC                              200.9M
MALLOC guard page                      64K
Memory tag=240                          4K
Memory tag=242                         12K
Memory tag=243                          8K
Memory tag=249                        156K
Memory tag=251                         32K
OpenCL                                 44K
OpenGL GLSL                          1936K
OpenGL GLSL (reserved)                128K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
SQLite page cache                    7776K
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                45.3M
VM_ALLOCATE                          17.0M
__DATA                               34.4M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                           79.3M
__TEXT                              261.0M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                         111.4M
shared memory                        31.6M
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                 1.8G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      869.4M

Model: Macmini5,1, BootROM MM51.0077.B10, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.76f0
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3034352E4130304C4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xE4), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.7f2 12718, 3 service, 21 devices, 3 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500.11 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8281, 0xfa113000 / 6
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Comment: Probably belongs in Apple's bug tracker. Try nuking your XCode settings. (Everything under `~/Library` that seems relevant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have experienced the same issue. Check this out:
[Xcode 5 crashes -- Xcode quit unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905900/xcode-5-crashes-xcode-quit-unexpectedly)

The quick solution is to disconnect source control. The good solution is dependant upon Apple that needs to fix their bug. I would therefore check the release notes of future Xcode releases.

Hope it helps. Best, Olavur