# XCode 5.x + Maverick crashes on File operations

Tags: ios, macos, xcode5, osx-mavericks

after updating my OS to Maverick, Xcode 5.01 started to crash every time a "file operation" is attempted.

With file operation I mean any operation that requires a file picker window to appear (e.g.: distribute an .ipa, add a file to the project, open a new project, etc) with a delay wich goes from seconds to split seconds.

The error is always the same:

```
Process:         Xcode [2802]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.1 (3335.23)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335023000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 84192765
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [273]
Responsible:     Xcode [2802]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-10-29 11:06:35.763 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  0AABAF71-6C8C-CCB9-2914-202CABCF1236


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A2053
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSRangeException): *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 27 beyond bounds [0 .. 15]
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff93661404 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00000001043a2df3 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff94d8fe75 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff9353f935 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff950631e3 -[IKImageFlowView _reloadCellDataAtIndex:] (in ImageKit)
  5  0x00007fff9506327e -[IKImageFlowView reloadCellDataAtIndex:] (in ImageKit)
  6  0x00007fff91a05221 -[FI_TFlowViewController(DataSource) reloadNodes:forNode:] (in FinderKit)
  7  0x00007fff919b9d9f -[FI_TBrowserViewController(DataSource) updatePropertiesForNodes:inContainerNode:] (in FinderKit)
  8  0x00007fff919d663b -[FI_TListViewController updatePropertiesForNodes:inContainerNode:] (in FinderKit)
  9  0x00007fff91ac16fd TNodeEngine::NodesChangedCallback(TFENode const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<TFENode, unsigned int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<TFENode, unsigned int> > > const&, TFENodeVector const&, TFENodeVector const&) (in FinderKit)
 10  0x00007fff91ac077b TNodeEngine::ProcessCompletion(TNodeEngineNotificationHandler*) (in FinderKit)
 11  0x00007fff91969033 IAsynchronousOperation::PerformSecondStepOnMainThread() (in FinderKit)
 12  0x00007fff9196926c ___ZN22IAsynchronousOperation30ScheduleSecondStepOnMainThreadEv_block_invoke (in FinderKit)
 13  0x00007fff934721d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff9346f2ad _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15  0x00007fff93476f03 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16  0x00007fff935c8839 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ (in CoreFoundation)
 17  0x00007fff93583b14 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 18  0x00007fff93583275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 19  0x00007fff9429af0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 20  0x00007fff9429acb7 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 21  0x00007fff9429aabc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 22  0x00007fff8a25628e _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 23  0x00007fff8a2558db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 24  0x00007fff8a5b4c5e -[NSApplication _realDoModalLoop:peek:] (in AppKit)
 25  0x00007fff8a5b336e -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] (in AppKit)
 26  0x00007fff8a880f3b -[NSSavePanel runModal] (in AppKit)
 27  0x00007fff8a70130b -[NSDocumentController beginOpenPanel:forTypes:completionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 28  0x00007fff8a701085 -[NSDocumentController beginOpenPanelWithCompletionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 29  0x00007fff8a700afd -[NSDocumentController openDocument:] (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff8a4743d0 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 31  0x0000000104a86bdf __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 32  0x00000001048b8764 -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 33  0x00007fff8a48f348 -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] (in AppKit)
 34  0x00007fff8a48f084 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] (in AppKit)
 35  0x00007fff8a4de4dd -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] (in AppKit)
 36  0x00007fff8a4de359 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] (in AppKit)
 37  0x00007fff8a485176 NSSLMMenuEventHandler (in AppKit)
 38  0x00007fff942746d4 DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) (in HIToolbox)
 39  0x00007fff94273c87 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) (in HIToolbox)
 40  0x00007fff94287d90 SendEventToEventTarget (in HIToolbox)
 41  0x00007fff942bda30 SendHICommandEvent(unsigned int, HICommand const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char, void const*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventRef**) (in HIToolbox)
 42  0x00007fff942f0618 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers (in HIToolbox)
 43  0x00007fff942f05c4 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent (in HIToolbox)
 44  0x00007fff942f04a5 FinishMenuSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*, MenuResult*) (in HIToolbox)
 45  0x00007fff942f8425 MenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, unsigned int, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) (in HIToolbox)
 46  0x00007fff942f8051 _HandleMenuSelection2 (in HIToolbox)
 47  0x00007fff8a3f779c _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent (in AppKit)
 48  0x00007fff8a25656e _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 49  0x00007fff8a2558db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 50  0x00007fff8a2499cc -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 51  0x00007fff8a234803 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 52  0x00007fff8aec35fd start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911335c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8eec1bba abort + 125
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010561d42f +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:reason:] + 775
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010561e67d -[IDEAssertionHandler handleUncaughtException:] + 919
5   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010561e728 IDEHandleUncaughtException + 77
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff942746fc DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 932
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff94273c87 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 385
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff94287d90 SendEventToEventTarget + 40
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff942bda30 SendHICommandEvent(unsigned int, HICommand const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char, void const*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventRef**) + 420
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff942f0618 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 59
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff942f05c4 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 178
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff942f04a5 FinishMenuSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*, MenuResult*) + 94
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff942f8425 MenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, unsigned int, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) + 718
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff942f8051 _HandleMenuSelection2 + 446
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a3f779c _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 284
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a25656e _DPSNextEvent + 2170
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a2558db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a2499cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a234803 NSApplicationMain + 940
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8aec35fd start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d0a662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9347143d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff93471152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d05a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d04d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93584315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93583939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93583275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84c907 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84c70b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d05a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d04d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93584315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93583939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93583275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000010e88681a -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 164
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84c70b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d099aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff935cfd43 __CFSocketManager + 867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89114c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8840fa38 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 656
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8840f78f startIOThread(void*) + 147
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d05a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d04d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93584315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93583939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93583275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a3f61ce _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d05a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d04d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93584315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93583939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93583275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84ea7c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d93770a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x000000011029f96b -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 132
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84c70b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89114c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010b18afd6 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84c70b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89114c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010b18afd6 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84c70b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89114c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000010b18afd6 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 506
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84c70b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89114c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d849a39 -[NSCondition wait] + 237
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d81621e -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 749
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d88472b -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 85
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff935bf384 ___forwarding___ + 452
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff935bf138 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
7   com.apple.imageKit              0x00007fff950597a6 -[IKTaskManager taskLoop] + 1580
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84c70b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 20:: com.apple.appkit-heartbeat
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09a3a __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8eee0e60 nanosleep + 200
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8eee0d52 usleep + 54
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a4ba2ad -[NSUIHeartBeat _heartBeatThread:] + 2132
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84c70b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89114c3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d849a39 -[NSCondition wait] + 237
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d81621e -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 749
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d815e6f -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 134
5   com.apple.imageKit              0x00007fff950936ef -[IKImageFlowView(tasks) nicestRenderingExpendStep] + 473
6   com.apple.imageKit              0x00007fff9509396f -[IKImageFlowView(tasks) nicestRenderingLoop] + 174
7   com.apple.imageKit              0x00007fff95059a0b -[IKTaskManager taskLoop] + 2193
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d84c70b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89113f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 26:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d05a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d04d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93584315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93583939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93583275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff936389d1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff8b5047e3 SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 355
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 27:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95d09a3a __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8eee0e60 nanosleep + 200
2   com.apple.CoreSymbolication     0x00007fff8bd3a681 0x7fff8bd27000 + 79489
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89112899 _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8911272a _pthread_start + 137
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89116fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff782f2310  rcx: 0x00007fff5b903908  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000707  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5b903930  rsp: 0x00007fff5b903908
   r8: 0x00007f8f63012a00   r9: 0x000000000000013c  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff5b903a48  r13: 0x0000000105cee378  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x00007f8f671ab7d0
  rip: 0x00007fff95d09866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x000000011cb4a000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000b8
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x1042fb000 -        0x1042fbff7  com.apple.dt.Xcode (5.0.1 - 3335.23) <1142F331-7D03-3CB2-813B-B02A520F1C31> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x104301000 -        0x10472eff7  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (5.0.1 - 3541) <D6D16715-8144-3828-8996-FE8B4DF883B2> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
       [oh, #%$#! I topped the 30000 character limit! You know what?! I'll cut a bit of stuff here: I'm sure nobody will notice ;-) ]
    0x7fff95d55000 -     0x7fff95d9cfff  libFontRegistry.dylib (127) <A77A0480-AA5D-3CC8-8B68-69985CD546DC> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff95ddb000 -     0x7fff95de2fff  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0) <8E26C099-CE9D-3819-91A2-64EA929C6137> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 2246
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=379.7M resident=241.4M(64%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=138.3M(36%)
Writable regions: Total=1.3G written=86.4M(6%) resident=194.1M(14%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.1G(86%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
CG backing stores                    14.0M
CG image                             14.3M
CG raster data                        264K
CG shared images                      212K
CoreAnimation                        15.4M
CoreData                                4K
CoreData Object IDs                  4100K
CoreGraphics                            4K
CoreImage                               8K
Dispatch continuations               8192K
Foundation                             16K
IOKit                                49.5M
IOKit (reserved)                        4K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Image IO                              216K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                       8K
MALLOC                              159.5M
MALLOC (admin)                         32K
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)                64K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Memory Tag 241                        100K
Memory Tag 242                         12K
Memory Tag 249                        156K
Memory Tag 251                         88K
OpenCL                                 40K
OpenGL GLSL                          1664K
SQLite page cache                    5248K
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                20.8M
VM_ALLOCATE                          21.7M
WebKit Malloc                        1232K
__DATA                               65.9M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                           90.8M
__TEXT                              289.2M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                         145.7M
shared memory                          68K
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                 1.9G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      965.2M


Model: MacBookPro6,1, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.53 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.57f18
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353432382D3034372E4130304C4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353432382D3034372E4130304C4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545050B9SA02, 500,11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS23N
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

the only sensible difference between the errors is the index that triggered of the "out of bound" exception, but trying again yields the same out of bound exception when in the same director.

The index in the exception seem to be connected to the particular directory where the file window is located at the time of the crash, the error:

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSRangeException): *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 27 beyond bounds [0 .. 15]
```

has become

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSRangeException): *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 27 beyond bounds [0 .. 14]
```

after I deleted a file in the directory.

Note that I used Xcode 5.0 on Mountain Lion with no problems at all: the errors started after the update to Maverick (updating to the last vesione of Xcode, v5.0.1, didn't help at all).

I apologize if this answer is a bit OT, but being SO a developer community I can't think of a better place where to post

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some digging I found the solution in this post:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23567487?tstart=0#23567487?tstart=0

Apparently, the .DS_Store files are confusing XCode quite a bit and removing all of them seem to resolve the problem (note that doing so might wipe some meta data from the folders containing it, like the icon position on the desktop).

*From a cursory analysis* it seems like the problem is generated only by .DS_Store files created by prior versions of the Operating System (e.g. Lion and Mountain Lion), as the new one doesn't seem to trigger the problem (this might be of some confort to those, like me, who want the icons in a specific place on their Desktops...).

Hope this helps

**UPDATE:** I have verified that this behavior is triggered by the newly created .DS_Store files as well. Until Apple solves this (embarrassing...) problem, I have installed on my system a one line script to clean a directory (and all it's children) of all .DS_Store files:

```
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" -name ".DS_Store" -exec rm -v "{}" ";"
```

and I run it periodically (or when a crash ensues) on the directories  I visit with XCode to arginate the problem.

Comment: I migrated my user and apps to a new Mavericks system and have noticed several applications (Sublime Text, Quicksilver, IntelliJ) crashing when doing "open file" on my home directory. This question and answer pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: I too have this problem, ran the script, problem solved.  Thanks.