# Xcode 5.0.2 crashes on load

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode5

I'm using Xcode `5.0.2` on os x mavericks `10.9.1` and i'm facing a strange problem as Xcode keeps loading for about 30 secs and then crashes when i opened it and do any mouse event i tried to unable the Source control as suggested in this post [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905900/xcode-5-crashes-xcode-quit-unexpectedly) but with no mean, the problem report is as follows:

```
Process:         Xcode [684]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335032000000000~4
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [142]
Responsible:     Xcode [684]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2014-01-19 16:18:32.647 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  04B4E5B4-74DF-8C99-FE04-776F426F8551


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8d33f0e6 objc_release + 22
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8d33e65a (anonymous   namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 502
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a716d72 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 50
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8da0c6ab -[__NSOperationInternal  _start:] + 913
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8da0c23b __NSOQSchedule_f + 64
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff94c772ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff94c7ef03  _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a793839 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a74eb14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a74e275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9518cf0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode +  226
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9518ccb7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9518cabc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8eda828e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8eda78db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ed9b9cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ed86803 NSApplicationMain + 940
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9345a5fd start + 1
```

I'm working on a Mac mini mid 2010 with processor 2.4 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo, Memory 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3, Does anyone know how to fix this and why this is happening? thanks in advance.

Comment: remove all projects' derived data

Comment: do you mean all the files exists in folder Show Package Contents ?

Comment: no Library/Developer/Derived Data or so -- just google Xcode remove derived data or so

Comment: i did that and it works well for a short time and the same problem occurs again !!

Comment: damn.. Im out of ideas then. thats my cure-all method :D

Comment: it is maybe due to a certain project? try to identify it.

Comment: when ever you have facing problem either project loading time or xcode  opening time., etc

Answer (score 1):

You might have an autosave problem where Xcode had trouble autosaving the project that keeps crashing. Go to the following location on your Mac:

```
/Users/YourUsername/Library/Autosave Information
```

Delete anything in there related to Xcode, such as files named Unsaved Xcode `Document.xcworkspace`. Restart Xcode and see if that fixes it.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23991398#23991398