# Xcode 6.4 quits unexpectedly in macOS Sierra?

Tags: xcode6.4, macos-sierra

I have many working projects built in Xcode 6.4(had OS X Yosemite).
Recently i updated to macOS Sierra.
And also i have installed Xcode version 7.3.1.
i.e. **i have multiple Xcode versions installed** following this link.
http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/install-multiple-versions-of-xcode.html

However i can open my projects in Xcode 7.3.1 but it shows too many errors. i want to open it in Xcode 6.4, which is giving me the error "**Xcode quit unexpectedly**." each time i reopen the project in Xcode 6.4

I tried this solutions, still no results

1. [Xcode quits unexpectedly every time I open my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600029/xcode-quits-unexpectedly-every-time-i-open-my-project)
2. [Xcode 5 crashes -- Xcode quit unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905900/xcode-5-crashes-xcode-quit-unexpectedly)

I understand there is some compatibility issue.
Is there any solution.SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems the problem is related to Ubiquity.framework being missing in newer OS versions. I managed to get the Xcode 6.4 to working on OS 10.12 with following:

Disable System Integrity Protection (SIP)

1. Restart your Mac.
2. Before OS X starts up, hold down Command-R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery.
3. From the Utilities menu, select Terminal.
4. At the prompt type exactly the following and then press Return: csrutil disable
5. Terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled.
6. From the  menu, select Restart.
   II. copy "OS X El Capitan 10.11.6" /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquiy.framework to "OS X Sierra" /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquity.framework

III. Enable System Integrity Protection (SIP)

credit goes to:
http://bbs.iosre.com/t/xcode-6-4-on-os-x-sierra/5453 to work:

Comment: @Kakopapppa:  Thanks for the response!!!, solution did worked for me....

Comment: Will my files be deleted using this process?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this solution](http://indiestack.com/2016/08/xcode-6-on-sierra/)
May be it helps.

Comment: To quote FrankerZ's comment on the deleted answer, "A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)"

Comment: Hey Sergey, Tried the above solution but problem is not solved yet. anyWay Thanks for the response man...

Answer (score 1):

Apple does recommend to upgrade to newer xcode versions. That would be fine IF the newer xcode versions would allow to run simulator on ALL the previsous iOS versions (which doesn't happen).

So if you need to support older devices (which if you do enterprise apps you are bound to need), you are stuck to use older xcode versions that still support the lowest hardware that you need to support.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.Out project is on xcode6.4.When i upgrade from mac 10.11 to 10.12.
Xcode 6.4 crashed when open.
I just downgraded to 10.11 back.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove a recent file `{PROJECT-FOLDER}/{YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}.entitlements`.