# XCode 5 crash on loading the project

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, crash, xcode5

My Xcode 5 crashes each time i want to open a project.

I deleted the derived data, the cache, the preferences and reinstall xcode.

I don't know what i should do know. I can't work.

Here is the failure message. PLease help me. I looked a lot about this in the internet.

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-3532/Framework/Classes/Protocols/DVTInvalidation.m:243
Details:  <IDESourceControlCredentialsValidator, 0x7f9f18c44cb0> was never invalidated.

Backtrace for allocation (if _creationBacktrace is set):
 (null)
Object:   <IDESourceControlCredentialsValidator: 0x7f9f18c44cb0>
Method:   -dealloc
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9f12c14bc0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001108fb188 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010f68d655 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010f68d984 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010f7626a6 _DVTInvalidation_DeallocSuper (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x00000001108982a3 -[IDESourceControlSSLAuthenticationWindowController .cxx_destruct] (in IDEKit)
  5  0x00007fff8703ffcc object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  6  0x00007fff87039922 objc_destructInstance (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  7  0x00007fff87039fa0 object_dispose (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  8  0x000000010f6b7995 __DVTSetupKVODeallocAssertions_block_invoke_371 (in DVTFoundation)
  9  0x00007fff82d347fa -[NSResponder dealloc] (in AppKit)
 10  0x00007fff82c6a162 -[NSWindowController dealloc] (in AppKit)
 11  0x00007fff82dde901 -[NSWindowController release] (in AppKit)
 12  0x00007fff82f145b0 -[NSAutounbinder dealloc] (in AppKit)
 13  0x00007fff8703a230 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) (in libobjc.A.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff80818d72 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop (in CoreFoundation)
 15  0x00007fff811cd47a -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] (in Foundation)
 16  0x00007fff82d3527e -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 17  0x00007fff82cd9bd6 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 18  0x00007fff82bb27e1 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 19  0x0000000000000002
```

Status update:

I started Xcode without loading the opened projects Alt + Shift. 
After that i unchecked Enabled Source Control in Preferences. Since now i can work with Xcode. That's not a fix, but for now it is ok. I look for an answer in future. For now I have no problems ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5 crashes with SVN version 1.7 - self signed certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890986/xcode-5-crashes-with-svn-version-1-7-self-signed-certificate)

Comment: Thanks that was the answer. I don't know why my Xcode crashed, but i have deactivated for now. I check it in future if it is working with svn. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Devforums post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/887478#887478) seems to have a possible solution.

> For anybody else reading this before a fix is found. My specific issue was resolved by using the correct hostname for the cert on the server. Our internal DNS could direct a more logical hostname to the svn server but it was not the same hostname that was in our cert. Using the correct hostname in the cert did away with the crashing.

Comment: I started Xcode without loading the opened projects Alt + Shift. After that i unchecked Enabled Source Control in Preferences. Since now i can work with Xcode. Thanks your answer helped me.
That's not a fix, but for now it is ok.

Answer (score 2):

This Problem can be solved by 
 Right click on xCode show package contents 
Navigate to 
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/
Rename the "**IDESubversion.ideplugin.hold**" to Some thing else

Answer (score 0):

I tried disabling the "Source control" - but Xcode would crash when I select "Source Control" tab in "Preferences". I tried some of the other things - deleting the ~/.subversion/auth/svn..... files/directories. NONE of that worked.

Finally what worked was renaming IDESubversion.ideplugin inside of Xcode.App to IDESubversion.ideplugin.old.

To do this - open "Application" on Finder. Click on Xcode.App and then "Control-click" on it. Select "Show Package Contents". Next find "IDESubversion.ideplugin". Click on it - it would change to edit name mode - change name by adding .old to the end.

After this XCode will allow you to select "Source Control" tab in "Xcode->Preferences". Deselect "Enable Source Control" and then open Xcode again and select the project you want to open. It should work. However, if you enable source control again or rename the IDESubversion.ideplugin.old to IDESubversion.ideplugin - the project/Xcode crashes again. So these two seems to be essential changes to make this work.

BTW, this is with OS X Mavericks update and to latest version of XCode (5A2053).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for me was to rename 
**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESubversion.ideplugin**

as muthukumar mentioned.

XCode crashed even if I clicked on Source Control in perferences...

@muthukumar thanks for that.