# XCode crashes on opening project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi I have problem with one of my projects and xcode 5.0.2 , xcode crashes on every atempt 
to open project. All other projects works fine. I tried checking out new version of project, reinstalling xcode, couple of other solutions from stackoverflow. Funny thing is that this project works fine on my coworkers machines it even works when I switch to other account on the same machine. Here is my crash log:

```
Process:         Xcode [2390]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335032000000000~4
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 106632651
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [169]
Responsible:     Xcode [2390]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-11-28 10:11:41.238 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11



Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-3542/Framework/Classes/XML/DVTXMLUnarchiver.m:452
Details:  Assertion failed: strcmp((const char *)xmlTextReaderConstName(xmlReader), elementNameCopy) == 0
Object:   <DVTXMLUnarchiver: 0x7fdd2981e9f0>
Method:   -decodeElementNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:success:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fdd22c114c0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001106e1ea8 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010f46c7a5 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010f46cad4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010f46ca82 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010f40fc2e -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeElementNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:success:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  5  0x000000010f40ecb6 -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x000000010f40f9cb -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeElementNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:success:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x000000010f40ecb6 -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeNodeWithXMLTextReader:owner:container:parsingState:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x000000010f40e874 -[DVTXMLUnarchiver _readAndReturnError:] (in DVTFoundation)
  9  0x000000010f40e61e -[DVTXMLUnarchiver decodeWithRootObject:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
 10  0x000000010fe46a09 -[IDEBreakpointBucket _decodeFromContainer:] (in IDEFoundation)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905900/xcode-5-crashes-xcode-quit-unexpectedly
or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969268/xcode-5-crash-on-loading-the-project

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project used some versioning git/svn. If yes, then you can follow these steps:

> Xcdoe > Preferences > Source Control > Uncheck the Enable Source
>   control

Might not helps you, but will be helpful for some one.

Comment: Source control is disabled.